# I want to watch multiple folders with fswatch on Mac

Tags: fswatch

I see in the documents for fswatch it has `$ fswatch -0 [opts] [paths] | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} [command]` but I don't really understand how I'm supposed to add multiple paths to that - I'm watching two paths `lib` and `test`. I've tried:
`fswatch -r lib,test`, `fswatch -r lib test`, and finally `fswatch -r [lib test]` How do I watch multiple paths with fswatch at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Separate the paths with a space (i.e. ' ')

For example:

```
fswatch "path/one" "path/two" echo "whatever"
```

Comment: This works perfectly! But then how do you know which one changed?

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I found is to execute the `fswatch` command multiple times:

```
do_backup() {
    // what you want to do
    rsync -ahhvzPR --delete $FILE $BACKUP_DIR
}

fswatch -r lib | while read FILE; do
    do_backup
done &

fswatch -r test | while read FILE; do
    do_backup
done &
```

This will start the process for both directories in detached mode.

More about the detached mode can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely).

Answer (score -1):

just use "," among the multi path.